# Android Oreo 8.0 Native C++ crash: invalid pthread_t passed to libc

Tags: android, c++, makefile, android-8.0-oreo

I have an Android Application that uses Cmake to compile native code into my application, and it was working great on A Pixel device running Android 7.1. I decided to upgrade my Pixel device to Oreo 8.0 and now I cannot enter the native C++ code in my app.

This is the logcat dump when it crashes:

```
A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/sailfish/sailfish:8.0.0/OPR3.170623.007/4286350:user/release-keys'
A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
A/DEBUG: pid: 29454, tid: 30950, name: Thread-24  >>> com.myapp.nativecppapp <<<
A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'invalid pthread_t 0x727d3004f0 passed to libc'
A/DEBUG:     x0   0000000000000000  x1   00000000000078e6  x2   0000000000000006  x3   0000000000000008
A/DEBUG:     x4   0000000000000000  x5   0000000000000000  x6   0000000000000000  x7   0000000000000030
A/DEBUG:     x8   0000000000000083  x9   222b2e8c5b032e6a  x10  0000000000000000  x11  0000000000000001
A/DEBUG:     x12  ffffffffffffffff  x13  0000000000000001  x14  0000000000000000  x15  000849a75d18b53a
A/DEBUG:     x16  00000072a8aee2f8  x17  00000072a8a905d0  x18  00000072a70fef30  x19  000000000000730e
A/DEBUG:     x20  00000000000078e6  x21  0000007286081ac0  x22  000000728609b998  x23  0000007286081a88
A/DEBUG:     x24  0000007286081ac4  x25  000000727d3fcee0  x26  000000727d3fceb8  x27  00000000000001cc
A/DEBUG:     x28  000000727fe6b000  x29  000000727d3fcc20  x30  00000072a8a44994
A/DEBUG:     sp   000000727d3fcbe0  pc   00000072a8a905d8  pstate 0000000060000000
A/DEBUG: backtrace:
A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00000000000695d8  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 000000000001d990  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+88)
A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 000000000002516c  /system/lib64/libc.so (__libc_fatal+116)
A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 0000000000066470  /system/lib64/libc.so (_Z23__pthread_internal_findl+164)
A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0000000000065fa8  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_detach+16)
A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 0000000000043528  /data/app/com.myapp.nativecppapp-SwBY2G1qycu-8Vec8QIe8w==/lib/arm64/libNativeLib.so
A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 000000000002a6e4  /data/app/com.myapp.nativecppapp-SwBY2G1qycu-8Vec8QIe8w==/lib/arm64/libNativeLib.so
A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 0000000000052430  /data/app/com.myapp.nativecppapp-SwBY2G1qycu-8Vec8QIe8w==/lib/arm64/libNativeLib.so
A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 000000000005176c  /data/app/com.myapp.nativecppapp-SwBY2G1qycu-8Vec8QIe8w==/lib/arm64/libNativeLib.so
A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 000000000004339c  /data/app/com.myapp.nativecppapp-SwBY2G1qycu-8Vec8QIe8w==/lib/arm64/libNativeLib.so
A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 0000000000065f88  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+36)
A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 000000000001ed24  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```

Here is the Cmake code that adds the shared library

```
add_library(NativeLib SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET NativeLib PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/NativeLib/Android/Release/${ANDROID_ABI}/libNativeLib.so")
```

The shared library then gets linked to the target.

As I said, this was all running flawlessly on Android 7.1 and upgrading the device to 8.0 caused this crash, is this a new bug? I did read the "Native Libraries" changes for 8.0 here https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html.

I also ran readelf on my library and got this back, which looks okay for 8.0:

```
LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x1b61c8 0x1b61c8 R E 0x10000
LOAD           0x1b6750 0x00000000001c6750 0x00000000001c6750 0x015fc0 0x085260 RW  0x10000
DYNAMIC        0x1c1010 0x00000000001d1010 0x00000000001d1010 0x0002c0 0x0002c0 RW  0x8
GNU_EH_FRAME   0x1871a0 0x00000000001871a0 0x00000000001871a0 0x006bac 0x006bac R   0x4
GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000000 0x000000 RW  0x10
GNU_RELRO      0x1b6750 0x00000000001c6750 0x00000000001c6750 0x00b8b0 0x00b8b0 R   0x1
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Dealing with this in while trying to connect to a socket...are there any work arounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in **__pthread_internal_find** function.

Before Android 8.0, if no thread can be found in the thread list, just a nullptr is returned. However, in Android 8.0, a fatal will be made.

This is requiring more careful handling of the POSIX stuff anyway...

See the last code block in [pthread_internal.cpp](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/bionic/pthread_internal.cpp#L129) for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Looks like that is what is causing the issue.

Comment: @mekostelecky did you find a fix/workaround for this?

Comment: How to know which function is causing it and where to fix

Comment: More details in bionic's doc on the following link : https://gerrit.pixelexperience.org/plugins/gitiles/bionic/+/HEAD/docs/status.md#invalid-handling-targetsdkversion-o